# CodeSandbox - PostCSS received undefined instead of CSS string

Tags: css, reactjs, codesandbox

I've uploaded a React project to CodeSandbox locally using the `codesandbox ./` terminal command.

CodeSandbox project link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/49pns?file=/src/App.js).

In the pane to view the project it's throwing the error, "PostCSS received undefined instead of CSS string". Because of this I am unable to view the project in the browser.

It's highlighting the first two lines of my code in my 'variables.scss' file as errors:

```
$light-primary: #fdebeb;
$light-grey: #f1f3f6;
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

What i would suggest you to do is have a main.scss - which will contain imports of other scss files, by doing this i was able to resolve the error -

```
// variables
@import "./variables";

// other
@import "./general";
@import "./typography";
```

Now import this in your App.js. - https://codesandbox.io/s/nce-forked-jh4py